I need tips to increase my sharepoint script performance
I created a script to export data to SharePoint Online. Basically, if there’s a change in AD, it should also update in SharePoint, or if the item doesn’t exist in SharePoint, it should then be created. Is there any way you see that could help me improve the script’s performance?
Import-Module PnP.PowerShell

$siteURL = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$primaryDomain = "mydomain.com"
$clientId = "5502516a-48c3-4b7d-b7a7-c42809bdf9a0"
$pfxPath = "C:\Users\f034067\OneDrive - Aethra Sistemas Automotivos S.A\Área de Trabalho\Pastas\Scripts\Scripts PowerShell\SharePoint Script\certificate.pfx"
$senhaPath = "C:\Users\f034067\OneDrive - Aethra Sistemas Automotivos S.A\Área de Trabalho\Pastas\Scripts\Scripts PowerShell\SharePoint Script\senha.txt"

try {
    $secureCertPassword = Get-Content $senhaPath | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($pfxPath, $secureCertPassword)
    
    $connectSplat = @{
        Url                 = $siteURL
        ClientId            = $clientId
        Tenant              = $primaryDomain
        CertificatePath     = $pfxPath
        CertificatePassword = $secureCertPassword
    }
    
    Connect-PnPOnline @connectSplat
    Write-Host "Autenticado no site SharePoint: $siteURL"
} catch {
    Write-Host "Não foi possível autenticar no site ou ler o certificado: $_"
    exit
}

$existingItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "Membros do grupo" -Fields "Colaborador", "Grupo"
$existingItemsHash = @{}
foreach ($item in $existingItems) {
    $key = "$($item["Colaborador"])|$($item["Grupo"])"
    $existingItemsHash[$key] = $item
}

$getADGroupSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = '(&(|(name=F_*)(name=G_*)(name=CAX_*))(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648))'
    Properties = 'Name', 'Info', 'Description', 'Member'
}

$groups = Get-ADGroup @getADGroupSplat
Start-PnPBatch

foreach ($gp in $groups) {
    Write-Host "Processando o grupo --> $($gp.Name)" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen

    if ($gp.Info -ne 'sem aprovador' -or $gp.Info -ne 'Sem aprovador') {
        $aprList = @()
        $aprovadores = if ($gp.Info) {
            $gp.Info -split "`r`n" | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } 
        } else { 
            @() 
        }

        foreach ($apr in $aprovadores) {
            if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($apr)) {
                $userSplat = @{
                    LDAPFilter = "(mail=$apr)"
                    Properties = 'mail'
                }
                
                $aprUser = Get-ADUser @userSplat
                if ($aprUser) {
                    $aprList += $aprUser.mail
                }
            }
        }

        $groupMemberSplat = @{
            Identity = $gp.Name
        }
        
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember @groupMemberSplat

        foreach ($mb in $members) {
            if ($mb.objectClass -eq "user") {
                $userDetailSplat = @{
                    LDAPFilter = "(samAccountName=$($mb.SamAccountName))"
                    Properties = 'DisplayName', 'Enabled'
                }
                
                $user = Get-ADUser @userDetailSplat
                if ($null -ne $user -and $user.Enabled) {
                    $key = "$($user.DisplayName)|$($gp.Name)"

                    $listItemSplat = @{
                        List   = "listname"
                        Values = @{
                            "Colaborador"     = $user.DisplayName
                            "Aprovadores"     = $aprList
                            "Grupo"           = $gp.Name
                            "Caminho"         = $gp.Description
                        }
                    }
                    
                    try {
                        if ($existingItemsHash.ContainsKey($key)) {
                            
                            Set-PnPListItem -List "listname" -Identity $existingItemsHash[$key].Id -Values $listItemSplat.Values -Batch
                            Write-Host "Item atualizado para o usuário $($user.DisplayName) no grupo $($gp.Name)"
                        } else {
                            
                            Add-PnPListItem -List "listname" -Values $listItemSplat.Values -Batch
                            Write-Host "Item adicionado para o usuário $($user.DisplayName) no grupo $($gp.Name)"
                        }
                    } catch {
                        Write-Host "Erro ao processar o usuário $($user.Name): $_"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Grupo definido para não ter aprovadores. Logo, não faz sentido tê-lo na gestão de acesso."
    }    
}

Invoke-PnPBatch
Disconnect-PnPOnline
Write-Host "Desconectado do SharePoint."

I appreciate your help!

You better avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection as it is inefficiënt. (especially on older versions of PowerShell). For more general scripting considerations, see: PowerShell scripting performance considerations. As for your you design: depending on how many users there are  and how many you eventually query, you might consider to preload  all ADUsers in once and index them based on their email.
